# Access to amp-state in amp-mustache templates or AMP.navigateTo

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I am trying to build an autocomplete input which is triggered upon clicking on a product. The input is to allow the user to select a city so that he can be landed on to the product details page with the city context.

To achieve this I store the product url in amp-state upon clicking on a product from a list of products, then when the user selects a city I want to navigate the user to product url with `cityId` as a query parameter. I am using `amp-list` with `amp-mustache` for autocomplete.

The code:

```
    <form action="//localhost/search/" id="citysuggest-form" on="submit:autosuggest-list.hide" target="_top" novalidate=""  hidden>
        <input autocomplete="off" i name="bysearch" on="input-debounced:AMP.setState({city_autosuggest: {autosuggest: event.value}}),autosuggest-list.show" placeholder="Search city..." required="" value="" type="text" [value]="autosuggest|| ''" class="search__form" autofocus>
        <span class="close" on="tap:autosuggest-list.hide,city__search.hide" role="button" tabindex="0">×</span>

    </form>
    <amp-selector layout="container" on="select:AMP.navigateTo(url='//localhost'+(selectProductUrl || '')+'?cityId='+event.targetOption)">
        <amp-list [src]="'//localhost/api/v2/autocomplete-amp/city/?record=5&term=' + (city_autosuggest.autosuggest || '')" height="110" hidden="" id="autosuggest-list" layout="responsive" src="//localhost/api/v2/autocomplete-amp/city/?record=5&term=" width="200" class="search__result-list">
            <template type="amp-mustache">
                <div class="search__result" option='{{payload.cityId}}' role="option" tabindex="0">{{result}}</div>
            </template>
        </amp-list>
    </amp-selector>
```

But the above throws error as the `url=` is not getting evaluated. Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: Can you post the error that is being thrown?

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Ashish we had to form the url on the server and then use it directly

Comment: I too did the same thing. :D